# Why is const in component function in class necessary

Tags: c++, class, constants

Say I create a class `Complex` with members `r`and `phi` that writes complex numbers in polar form through the constructor

`Complex (double Re=0, double Im=0) : r(sqrt(Re*Re + Im*Im)), phi(atan2(Im,Re)) {}`

In the class I find component functions like

`double real() const
{return r*cos(phi);}`

which seem logical, but I do not understand the neccessity of `const` (is there a difference between `const double real()` and `double real() const`?)

I have been told that it is important such that the component function does not modify the class.

Modify in what sense? Surely no members of the class will be added or removed because of a component function, and how would `const`actually avert this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spend some time reading up on [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Comment: "is there a difference between const double real() and double real() const" - Yes. In the first case `const` applies to the return value (and is quite pointless) in the second it applies to the `this` pointer of the object the function is invoked on (not pointless).

Comment: Modify in the sense that `double real() const { r = 1; return r*cos(phi);}` will result in a compiler error while `double real() { r = 1; return r*cos(phi);}` will not. As a rule of thumb you can make methods `const` by default and only if they need to modify the object remove the `const`